# Plugin or way to search in a string in Node

Tags: node.js, string

I have to compare movies title and find the title who's matching the best but i don't know if there is a way to accomplish this.

Here is 2 examples:

In my file i have 2 titles:

- star wars : episode II : l'attaque des clones
- mars attacks !

In the API the titles are:

- star wars, épisode II - l'attaque des clones
- mars attacks!

I do some cleaning with regex for replacing '-' by ':' but there is so many exceptions to check.

I want to know if a tool exists or a way to do for match strings when some same words appears.

Sorry for my english and thank you for your help

**EDIT :** Ok i research "approximate string matching node js" in google and seems this is what i want, fuzzy-matching.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Could you post some example code or inputs and outputs?

Comment: In clear i want "star wars : episode II : l'attaque des clones" match with "star wars, épisode II - l'attaque des clones". They are some differences like '-' and ':', or ','. Actually i do a simple "==" comparison and it don't match some movies

Comment: Instead of changing your dataset, you should look at one of two options to use at search time: using regex to specify character sets like `[-:]` when you search, or using a fuzzy-match library which will implement a partial match algorithm for you. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/fuzzy-string-matching/ for instance.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i have edit my answer